# What should ex.class be equal to here?

Tags: ruby, methods, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to learn ruby by using the code downloaded from [this website](http://rubykoans.com/).

I got stuck at this point.

```
  def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil
    # What happens when you call a method that doesn't exist.  The
    # following begin/rescue/end code block captures the exception and
    # makes some assertions about it.
    begin
      nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
    rescue Exception => ex
      # What exception has been caught?
      assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class

  # What message was attached to the exception?
  # (HINT: replace __ with part of the error message.)
  assert_match(/__/, ex.message)
end
```

end

I'm supposed to replace __ with part of the error message, but I haven't been successful. Well, I was, because after a few tries I just replaced it with a space, since I figured that the error message had spaces between the words. But how am I supposed to see what the error message is?

Comment: right your example does work with NoMethodError in my console. Could you post the error message then?

Comment: I think I made a mistake when I posted my question, so I updated it.

Answer (score 6):

You will get a NoMethodError here:

```
>> def tst
>>   nil.an_unknown_meth
>> rescue Exception => ex
>>   puts ex.class
>>   puts ex.message
>> end
 => nil 

>> tst
NoMethodError
undefined method `an_unknown_meth' for nil:NilClass
```

So `NoMethodError` for a class, and `/undefined method .* for nil:NilClass/` as a message should fit.

More info on [NoMethodError](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/NoMethodError.html) and [generally on Ruby Exceptions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html) in ruby-docs